# "feeling nostalgic {for/of/about} summer sunsets”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition is needed in the gap; is it *for*, *of*  or *about*?

> I am feeling nostalgic _____ summer sunsets.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nostalgic)

- *and aging hippies **nostalgic for** their youth.*

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nostalgic)

- *She was **nostalgic about** the past and did not like the ways in which society had changed*

Comment: See [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nostalgic+for%2C+nostalgic+of%2C+nostalgic+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: @Heartspring Your edit changed the question too much. That is really something the OP should do.